# How do I style my accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I've created an accordion and it looks very basic. I want tips to make it look more stylish and having a hovering effect. I've also attached few screenshots of the section of my website. I think that section looks the ugliest, Is there any tip to design that section any better?

P.S - I have less than 10 reputation and I can't post more than two links so i'm using (dot) for linking to my images.

Screenshots:

imgur(dot)com/a/dCw2H

imgur(dot)com/a/UcSfF

imgur(dot)com/a/4J9Xa

**Here's the code**

```
 #wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            }

         .accordionButton {
            width: 100%;

            background: #7cfc00;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #fff;
            }

         .accordionContent {
            width: 100%;

            background: #fff;
             padding: 0.9375em;

     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     color: #777;
     font-size: 10pt;
     line-height: 16pt;
            }
```

**html code**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="accordionButton">monday</div>
        <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
        <div class="accordionButton">tuesday</div>
        <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
        <div class="accordionButton">wednesday</div>
        <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br />more weather</div>
        <div class="accordionButton">thursday</div>
        <div class="accordionContent">sunny<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />more weather</div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gok6bar7/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: 1. in your jsfiddle the accordion doesn't have any functionality.
2. make your accordion look that it ' belongs ' to your website ( colors, fonts, etc. ) . don't know what exactly do you want from us . It's a question that would receive very `opinion-based` answers

Comment: I just want to look it good with the background and having a hover effect. like the accordion is floating over the background. I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are a asking a mostly design related question, which will get varied answers depending on who you ask. Some basic suggestions to make your site look 'good' and to improve overall ease of use are:

1. Pick a color scheme - Their are a lot of colors fighting for attention on your page. Simple is generally best, I would try replacing the lime green.
2. Make text readable - The white text on lime green feels aggressive and unreadable. For white text to be readable make sure to use a dark background.
3. Differentiate between different types of text - Try making the fontsize of your accordionButton class larger (as it is a heading) or using a different font or font weight entirely.
4. Let content breathe - Try including more space (padding) around the text in your accordion to open the layout up a bit. When items are too close together they are confusing to look at.

This is just a starting suggestion! There are lots of great articles about basic web design floating around. Here's one to get you started.

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/myfirstsite/basicwebdesign.html